# A column of a table needs to stay in one line (HTML/CSS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am having an issue on [my entrepreneur business opportunity rating matrix](http://www.stoeffler.cc/entrepreneur-tool-business-opportunity-rating-matrix/) :
I would like the radio buttons to stay on the same line.
The problem is that I don't know how I should process because if I give a fixed minimum width for the cell, i'm not sure it will display properly on other browsers, and if the cell is to big I loose the alignment of the radio buttons.

Do you guys have a CSS/Javascript (jQuery) trick that would fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's easy: Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to your td.

Answer (score 0):

I would redesign the table layout (note this is a quick and dirt solution) to place the buttons below the labels (you save space in smaller window sizes).

```
<tr class="even">
  <td rowspan="2">Customer atlernatives</td>
  <td class="col_g left-aligned">A lot</td>
  <td class="col_d right-aligned">Few</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td class="col_m centered">
    <form method="post" action="action" class="bz_op_val">
      <input type="radio" value="4" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="38">
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

a better solution should be, to me:

```
<tr class="even">
  <td>Customer atlernatives</td>
  <td>
    <div class="col_g left-aligned">A lot</div>
    <div class="col_d right-aligned">Few</div>
    <form method="post" action="action" class="bz_op_val cleared-both-centered">
      <input type="radio" value="4" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="38">
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="38">
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```